# imagemagick - Restrict elaboration to a region of the image

Tags: imagemagick

I need to process a large amount of scans of dot matrix printed documents in order to optimize them for reading with an ocr engine.
I used imagemagick to make sure that there are no white spaces between the points of the matrix, so the ocr engine works much better. The problem is performance, pdfs are scanned at 600dpi and processing takes too long. I would like to limit the processing only to the area affected by the zonal ocr, I tried with the "-region" operator but even if it works, the processing takes the same time.
This is the command used by the windows command line:

```
convert -density "601.6x600" -units pixelsperinch -monochrome files\1.pdf -region 2000x200+2500+2100 -negate -morphology Thinning "17x17+8+8: -,-,-,-,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,- -,-,-,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,- -,-,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,- -,-,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0,0,-,- -,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0,0,- 0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0,0 0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0 0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0 0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,1,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0 0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0 0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0 0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0,0 -,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0,0,- -,-,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0,0,-,- -,-,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,- -,-,-,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,- -,-,-,-,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-" -morphology Thinning "13x13+6+6: -,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,- -,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,- 0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0 0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0 0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0 0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0 0,0,-,-,-,-,1,-,-,-,-,0,0 0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0 0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0 0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0 0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0 -,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,- -,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-" -morphology Close Disk -negate -compress zip r.pdf
```

P.S. I wanted to post on the imagemagick forum, but I didn't find the link to subscribe ...

Comment: The time is likely spent rasterizing the PDF

Comment: no, if i remove morphology it is much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved here https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/2841.

the -region param appears to act after the processing of entire file. Fixed using clone, crop, layer and flatten:

```
magick in.tiff ( +clone -crop 100x100+500+500 -morphology dilate disk ) -layers flatten x2.tiff
```